# Creating a logic app that will trigger workflow of retrieving user data

Tags: performance

How to create a logic app to perform a task like filters out guest users who have not signed in within the last 60 days? Can someone please help

I created the logic app, I started by designing
My first action was Recurrence
Get user
I'm stock with **filter array** I can’t get pass this action